# AvPlayer hangs and stop streaming big size audio url

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using AvPlayer to stream and play audio file from url. my code is working fine with small size url but stop playing big size audios.please help me to resolve this issue..

here is my code

```
-(void)playAudioFeeds:(NSString *)audioStr{

    AVPlayerItem *audioPlayerItem;
    [self enableObserver:NO onObject:audioPlayerItem addObserver:self];
    audioPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:audioStr]];
    [self enableObserver:YES onObject:audioPlayerItem addObserver:self];
    self.audioFeedsPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:audioPlayerItem];
    [self.audioFeedsPlayer play];
}
```

and code to add observer is..

```
- (void)enableObserver:(BOOL)enable onObject:(AVPlayerItem *)object addObserver:(id)observer {

      if (enable) {

      [object addObserver:observer forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
      [[object valueForKey:@"player"] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];       
       NSLog(@"Enable KYObserver");
      } else {
            @try {
                 [object removeObserver:observer forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" context:nil];
                 [[object valueForKey:@"player"] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];
                  NSLog(@"Remove KYObserver");
            } @catch (NSException *__unused exception) {
               NSLog(@"Exceptions occurs on removing the KYObserver");
             }
         }
    } 


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
// check that all conditions for a stuck player have been met

      AVPlayer *player = [object valueForKey:@"player"];
      NSLog(@"In OVKP of songPlayer");
      NSLog(@"keyPath:%@",keyPath);

      if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {

           if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
           NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");

           } else if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
                   NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");

                   } else if (player.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
                       NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

                     }

               }

        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"]) {
              if (player.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp == NO &&
                   CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(player.currentTime, >, kCMTimeZero) &&
                   CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(player.currentTime, !=, player.currentItem.duration))
                     {
                       NSLog(@"Hanged");

                       [player performSelector:@selector(play) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

                      }

                 }

            }
```

Comment: You are sure these do not stop because of the buffer?

Comment: I dont know  how to see buffer status while playing? My player just stops and gives message "Media services Reset"..please notice that i am using two avPlayers one for background audio and one for live streaming(this is the one that stops).